# Use of the word "Overjoyous"

Tags: word-choice

Is the following correct:

The overjoyous Scottish supporter could hardly believe his eyes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[overjoyous](http://universalium.academic.ru/166085/overjoyous)**     adj.; overjoyously, adv.; overjoyousness, n.

Also found in the **Useful english dictionary**. 2012.

> Well, my narratives regarding my S.S. Beagle voyage have been
>   published, and just a few months later, Emma and I had our first
>   child, a boy we named William Erasmus Darwin. **Despite this overjoyous
>   news**, I am pained constantly by migrains, heart and stomach problems,
>   and nausea. I returned to my hometown of Shrewsbury to have my father
>   examine me, to no avail. Because of this, I’ve gotten little work
>   done. Charles Darwin 1840

Answer (score 1):

No, because overjoyous is [not a word](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overjoyous). Maybe you are thinking of the word **overjoyed**.

Comment: overjoyous http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/overjoyous

Answer (score -2):

The word overjoyous doesn't exist. It would be better to say "The Scottish supporter, who was overjoyed to (verb) could hardly believe his eyes.
Someone is overjoyed to hear/see/find etc something.
Someone is also overjoyed at something.

Comment: Or simply ''The overjoyed Scottish supporter could hardly believe his eyes.''

Comment: @Archa What is your point?  The OP did not ask if  'overjoyed' was a substitute.  Your responsive is not constructive

Comment: I was answering to Ana Luiza Sardenberg's message.